# How to clear Multiselect Dropdown in Semantic UI React using a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have a Semantic UI React Multiselect Dropdown inside a React functional component and want to have buttons inside the menu, as such (still need to center them...)

[image: buttons in dropdown]

How can I clear the selected values using the 'Clear' button?
I am able to clear the selection using the 'x' icon, but that's built into the component.

```
    <Dropdown
        search
        multiple
        selection
        clearable
        closeOnSelectionChange={false}
        options={filterInitialSuggestions()}
        className='selectDropdown'
        header={dropdownButtons()}
    />
        
    const dropdownButtons = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button positive size='mini'>
                    Save
                </Button>
                <Button grey size='mini' onClick={() => console.log('I want to reset the multi select dropdown')}>
                    Clear
                </Button>
                <Divider />
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Comment: You need to have control over a component (called controlled component) - it's when you provide the values and all things (if put simply). They do support it - https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-controlled

Comment: It looks like the parent component needs to change and the child needs to listen to the change. In my case, my child is changing ('clear' button is clicked) and the parent needs to listen. Is that possible with controlled components?

Comment: You need to have a selected values in state of parent component and pass it down to child - this is exactly what controlled component is doing

Comment: I see. There needs to be an external value in state which both observe. If one changes, the other sees it. Right?

Comment: I would not call it "observe". Parent passes value down to child - that's it. Like in normal react, like with normal inputs

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Save' and 'Clear' buttons with React `useState()`. In Reactjs you don't need to use DOM queryselector.

https://codesandbox.io/s/white-leftpad-q6re3?file=/src/Fun.jsx

Comment: Hey, thanks for the codesandbox! Your example works exactly as I wanted it to, it must have been `value` that I was missing. I can't get it working for me, though. It won't select items. I even tried copy/pasting your working code exactly into my project, but no go.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';


const options = [
    { key: 1, text: 'Choice 1', value: 1 },
    { key: 2, text: 'Choice 2', value: 2 },
    { key: 3, text: 'Choice 3', value: 3 },
    { key: 4, text: 'Choice 4', value: 4 },
    { key: 5, text: 'Choice 5', value: 5 },
    { key: 6, text: 'Choice 6', value: 6 },
]


class Example extends Component {

    state = {
        dropval: []
    }

    onDropChange = (e, { value }) => {
        this.setState(
            (prevState) => { return { ...prevState, dropval: value } },
            // () => console.log(this.state)
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Dropdown
                    search
                    multiple
                    selection
                    clearable
                    closeOnSelectionChange={false}
                    options={options}
                    className='selectDropdown'
                    onChange={this.onDropChange}
                    value={this.state.dropval}
                    style={{ width: 300 }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: Thanks for your submission. Some problems with your answer: I am using functional components, not class ones (so no state). Secondly, this component hides the values somewhere, not in the state (otherwise I would just use useState), which is the entire reason I asked the question. Storing the values outside the component makes it stop working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve this issue. I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it seems to work decently.

```
    const dropdownButtons = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <div className='dropdown-saveButton'>
                    <Button
                        positive
                        size='mini'
                        onClick={() => {
                            saveValues();
                        }}
                    >
                        Save
                    </Button>
                    <Button size='mini' onClick={clearDropdown}>
                        Clear
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <Divider inverted />
            </>
        );
    };

const clearDropdown = e => {
        var element = dropdownRef.current.querySelector('[aria-selected="true"]');
        if (element) {
            dropdownRef.current.querySelector('.clear')?.click();
        }
    };

                     <Dropdown
                            multiple
                            selection
                            fluid
                            clearable
                            header={dropdownButtons} />
```